# .gitignore not ignoring filenames with spaces in them on `git status`

Tags: git, gitignore

When I do a `git status` I get:

```
#       modified:   COM/config/Config/Edit Project Settings.lnk
```

But in my .gitignore I have:

```
*.lnk
```

What is going on here? Could it be a problem with whitespaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so my problem actually was that the files where already in the repository, so adding the pattern to `.gitignore` did not prevent git from tracking changes on them.

What was needed was

`git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>`

Now their changes are not tracked anymore.

Else as ansh0l pointed out git handles spaces perfectly fine.

Comment: This works only till you don't do a pull. AFAIK, you have to set this every time after doing a pull

Comment: This is really not a good solution. If you want that file in the repository, then you would also want the changes to that file. If you don't want it in the repository, then simply remove it as 
ansh0l says. If you want to keep an older version, you can restore it's older version.

Comment: Think about config files or link files (aka shortcuts) under windows. Since shortcuts update their targets i don't want them to show modifications as it will change for every user. Sometimes some things are defined by people who don't know better and they are in a position where you can't argue with them but have to live with their decisions.

Comment: `--assume-unchanged` is risky, if you do a checkout that would modify that file (because you switched to a branch that doesn't have it, for example) the checkout will simply fail (even `--force`d!), until you `--no-assume-unchanged` that file

Answer (score 9):

The problem is not with the whitespaces.

I think the file is already tracked in your git repo, so you can remove it from the repo using the following:

```
git rm -r --cached "COM/config/Config/Edit Project Settings.lnk"
git commit -m "removed .lnk"
```

This won't delete the `.lnk` file, only untrack it locally (Though it will delete on other folks machines once this commit goes upstream)